# Regex - Matching a pattern not containing a string

Tags: java, regex

I have seen other similar questions, but they were all about matching at the start of at the end, and this is not what i'm looking for.

I want to match parameters with the syntax :

`{{param-name}}` or `{{param-name=default value}}`

So far i have the following regular expression :

```
(\{\{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:=.*)?\}\})
```

But the problem is that if there is more than one parameter, it create only one match : from the beginning of the first to the end of the last one. For example :

```
bla bla {{foo=blabla}} bla bla {{bar=hehe}} bla bla
```

Will match : `{{foo}} bla bla {{bar=hehe}}` while i want `{{foo}}` and `{{bar=hehe}}`

So i need to check that, after the `=` character, there is no `}}` string before the `}}` terminating the parameter.

I don't know how to do that. Can you help me ?
Thank you :)

PS : I'm using that in Java if it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the `.*` after `=` as non-greedy.

```
(\{\{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:=.*?)?\}\})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/2)

Java regex would be,

```
"(\\{\\{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:=.*?)?\\}\\})"
```

**OR**

```
(\{\{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:=(?:(?!}}).)*)?\}\})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/3)

In this, i modified `.*?` inside the optional non-capturing group with `(?:(?!}}).)*`.

- `(?!..)` called negative lookahead assertion. This won't match any character but asserts that the match would occur in a particular place or not. Here `(?!}}).` Checks the condition that the character we are going to match wouldn't be `}}`. That is the following character won't be the first closing curly bracket in `}}`
- If yes, then only the corresponding character will be matched.
- So this `(?:(?!}}).)*` Matches any character but not of `}}` zero or more times. `?` next to the `*` makes the `*` to do a non-greedy match. Note that this would match a single closing curly bracket.

Code:

```
String s = "bla bla {{foo}} bla bla {{bar=hehe}} bla bla";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:=(?:(?!}}).)*)?\\}\\}").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
{{foo}}
{{bar=hehe}}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Could you explain me the second option ? I've seen things about the ?! operator but I didnt understand them. Thx.

Comment: Yeah its clearer thanks, but i realize that this has a problem. Only the first parameter is matched as you can see here : `https://www.regex101.com/r/aQ4mF3/1`. Why isn't the second one matched too ?

Comment: Thanks, but how do you add the global flag in java ? I tried srrounding my reg exp with / and /g, but it doesn't seem to work. And there is no "GLOBAL" flag in the class Pattern which i would pass as a parameter.

Comment: you don't need to add global flag in java. It would do the match globally. See my example.

Comment: Ok i found my problem. THere is no global flag to add, i just needed to call find() until no more match is found. I thought that a single call to find() was enough to find them all.

Answer (score -1):

In Java Normally All Regular Expressions work fine, but the syntax changes.
use Double slash('\') instead of single.

Try This :

```
(\\{\\{[A-Za-z0-9_-]*(?:=.*)?\\}\\})
```